# Finding an index of element in vector and removing it

Tags: c++, vector, unordered-set

I have a loop. If a certain condition is true, I need to add an item to a vector. If it's false instead, I need to remove an item from the vector.

Here is my best attempt at reproducing what I am trying to do:

```
#include <iterator>
#include <vector>
#include <algorithm>
#include <memory>

struct Arrow
{
    std::vector<Arrow*> inRange;
};

int main()
{
    std::vector<std::unique_ptr<Arrow>> arrows;
    for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
        arrows.push_back(std::make_unique<Arrow>());

    for (int i = 0; i < arrows.size(); i++)
        for (int j = 0; j < arrows.size(); j++)
            if (i != j)
            {
                bool someCondition = true;//obviously can be false as well in the actual code
                if (someCondition)
                    arrows[i]->inRange.push_back(arrows[j].get());
                else
                {
                    std::vector<Arrow*> itr = std::find(arrows[i]->inRange.begin(),
                        arrows[i]->inRange.end(), arrows[i]);

                    int index = std::distance(arrows[i]->inRange, itr);
                    arrows[i]->inRange.erase(itr.begin(), index);
                }
            }
}
```

I am completely unfamiliar with all of this and have no idea what is going wrong.  Thank you for helping.

Errors:

```
Severity    Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
Error (active)  E0312   no suitable user-defined conversion from "std::_Vector_iterator<std::_Vector_val<std::conditional_t<true, std::_Simple_types<Arrow *>, std::_Vec_iter_types<Arrow *, size_t, ptrdiff_t, Arrow **, Arrow *const *, Arrow *&, Arrow *const &>>>>" to "std::vector<Arrow *, std::allocator<Arrow *>>" exists   steer away  C:\Users\me\source\repos\steer away\steer away\main.cpp 26
```

```
Severity    Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
Error (active)  E0304   no instance of overloaded function "std::vector<_Ty, _Alloc>::erase [with _Ty=Arrow *, _Alloc=std::allocator<Arrow *>]" matches the argument list   steer away  C:\Users\me\source\repos\steer away\steer away\main.cpp 30
```

```
Severity    Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
Error (active)  E0304   no instance of function template "std::distance" matches the argument list  steer away  C:\Users\me\source\repos\steer away\steer away\main.cpp 29
```

```
Severity    Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
Error (active)  E0304   no instance of overloaded function "std::vector<_Ty, _Alloc>::erase [with _Ty=Arrow *, _Alloc=std::allocator<Arrow *>]" matches the argument list   steer away  C:\Users\me\source\repos\steer away\steer away\main.cpp 30
```

```
Severity    Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
Error (active)  E0304   no instance of function template "std::distance" matches the argument list  steer away  C:\Users\me\source\repos\steer away\steer away\main.cpp 29
```

```
Severity    Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
Error   C2893   Failed to specialize function template 'iterator_traits<_Iter>::difference_type std::distance(_InIt,_InIt)' steer away  C:\Users\me\source\repos\steer away\steer away\main.cpp 29
```

```
Severity    Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
Error   C2664   'std::_Vector_iterator<std::_Vector_val<std::_Simple_types<_Ty>>> std::vector<_Ty,std::allocator<_Ty>>::erase(std::_Vector_const_iterator<std::_Vector_val<std::_Simple_types<_Ty>>>,std::_Vector_const_iterator<std::_Vector_val<std::_Simple_types<_Ty>>>) noexcept(<expr>)': cannot convert argument 2 from 'int' to 'std::_Vector_const_iterator<std::_Vector_val<std::_Simple_types<_Ty>>>'    steer away  C:\Users\me\source\repos\steer away\steer away\main.cpp 30
```

Comment: *"loads of different errors, so I am not sure which one to post"* All of them, verbatim.

Comment: `unordered` containers are ill suited for index-based operations. There isn't really any kind of meaning you can attribute to an index based range of elements in an `unordered` container. Trying to do so probably indicates a logic error.

Comment: I assume you're asking for `arrows[i]->inRange.erase(arrows[j].get());`. But it doesn't make much sense, because the sets are initially empty.

Comment: @FrançoisAndrieux I initially had a vector, but someone suggested I use unordered set. I will be fine with answer that uses vector as well. I can change the question.

Comment: @Apple_Banana If you used a vector and relied on manipulating ranges of elements then changing to a `set` or `unordered_set` completely changes the logic. The index in a vector is related to order of insertion, but in associative containers that order is not preserved. It isn't clear to me what the code is trying to achieve, so it is hard to make a recommendation.

Comment: @FrançoisAndrieux Forget about unordered_set. I edited the question and as you can see I literally just changed `insert` to `push_back`. That is all. Just make a recommendation in terms of vector and how you would solve the problem because I just glued together the solution from different web sites and is probably not good.

Comment: @FrançoisAndrieux The problem being finding the index of particular element I want to remove and removing it.

Comment: @Apple_Banana -- `std::vector<Arrow*> itr = std::find` ==> `auto itr = std::find` is much easier and is correct, while your attempt is harder and wrong.

Comment: @Apple_Banana If you ignore the part about index, and you just want to remove a particular element, you can do so with both `vector` and `set`. Containers (except `std::array`) have an `erase` member which take a single argument, an iterator to the object to erase. This is what `std::find` returns. So `inRange.erase(itr)` ought to do it, whichever the container. Note that `std::unordered_set` and `std::set` have a member function `find` which will be better than `std::find`. That is the main purpose of using sets.

Comment: I doubt you can `std::find` in a vector of `Arrow*` (`arrows[i]->inRange`) a `unique_ptr` (`arrows[i]`). Your code seems to me a little convoluted: I'm curious what are you trying to achieve?

Comment: @MatG So the each arrow in arrows has a certain field of view. If any arrow in arrows is within the field of view of any other arrow,  it needs to get added to inRange vector of that arrow and it it isn't then it needs to get removed. `someCondition` bool in the above code is true if it is in the fov and is false if it isn't. So basically, If an arrow1 is in fov of arrow2, arrow2 needs to get added to arrow1.inRange.

Comment: @MatG And I am stuck in the removing part.

Comment: @FrançoisAndrieux But I cannot ignore the part about index :). That is the main problem for me right now.

Comment: @Apple_Banana Ah ok, I'm starting to understand, I'll think about it. Have you added `.get()`?

Comment: If the element is found i.e. the iterator is not end, you can just pass the iterator to the erase function of vector. No need to find the index. The iterator already points to it.

Comment: @MatG add it to what ?

Comment: Also, if you pass two iterators to erase, you remove a range. Do you want that? Else pass only one.

Comment: @JHBonarius I am not sure what you mean.

Comment: If `itr = std::find(...)` then if `itr != inRange.end()` an element is found, which you can delete using `inRange.erase(itr)`

Comment: @JHBonarius But there is an error on that line. `itr = std::find(...)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I second the choice of `vector`, but since adding and removing items in a loop can be tricky and not so efficient I'd skip the adding and removing thing by starting from an empty container and then just adding, so this doesn't address directly your question but shows how I'd approach your problem. (code not compiled, may contain errors):

```
class Arrow
{
    /* ... */
    void clear_inrange_arrows(const std::size_t n)
    {
        m_inrange.clear();
        // This ensures just one dynamic allocation
        if(m_inrange.capacity()<n) m_inrange.reserve(n);
    }
    bool is_inrange_of(const Arrow& const other) const noexcept { /* ... */ }
    void add_inrange_arrow(const Arrow& const other)
    {
        m_inrange.push_back(&other);
    }

 private:
    std::vector<const Arrow*> m_inrange; // Arrows in range, owned by 'World'
};

// Allow me introduce something that manages
// the memory and performs the operation
class World
{
    /* ... */
    std::vector<Arrow> all_the_arrows;

    /* ... */
    void precalculate_whos_inrange()
    {
    // For each existing arrow (you could use `auto` here)...
    for(std::vector<Arrow>::iterator icurr=all_the_arrows.begin(); icurr!=all_the_arrows.end(); ++icurr)
       {
        // ...Clear previous 'in-range' arrows container, and then...
        icurr->clear_inrange_arrows(all_the_arrows.size());
        // ...Add the other arrows in range
        for(auto iother=all_the_arrows.begin(); iother!=icurr; ++iother)
            if( icurr->is_inrange_of(*iother) ) icurr->add_inrange_arrow(*iother);
        for(auto iother=icurr+1; iother!=all_the_arrows.end(); ++iother)
            if( icurr->is_inrange_of(*iother) ) icurr->add_inrange_arrow(*iother);
       }
};
```

Then I'd consider if this precalculation is really necessary, and to remove `m_inrange` from `Arrow` at all putting it locally just where this information is needed.